# Why is my number format choking?

Tags: d3.js, formatting

I have a bunch of numbers in the millions. I want to use them in labels on my d3 bar chart, formatted like `$23M` -- but for some reason, my decimals are sticking around.

My read of [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting#d3_format) says that `$,.0f` should work, if I first divide by `1000000`.

I have `var millions = d3.format("^$,.f");` and then I call it later with

```
.text(function(d) {
   return (millions(d.money / 1000000) + "M");
 })
```

I'm still seeing digits after the decimal. What am I doing wrong?

I found a [handy site](http://bl.ocks.org/zanarmstrong/raw/05c1e95bf7aa16c4768e/) that demonstrates a variety of formatting strings on any number you give it, and when I plug my format in, it looks like it ought to work, but in my code, it doesn't work.

Tinkerable version at https://jsfiddle.net/a1ppt754/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
var millions = d3.format("^$,.f");
```

do this way

```
var millions = d3.format("^$f");
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/anobxr86/)

Comment: OOps! thats a copy paste mistake..from your earlier post make it `var millions = d3.format("^$f");`